# In OS X, how can I view the calendar from the clock?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, calendar

In OS X, is there a way to view the calendar by clicking the clock icon in the top right corner of the screen?

(Similar to how in Windows you can just double click the clock in the bottom left corner of the screen and a calendar appears).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a widget in Dashboard called iCal which displays a simple calendar. If you click it once, it'll display a list of today's events as well.

If you're unfamiliar with Dashboard, it can be launched either by clicking the Dashboard icon in the Dock (unless it's been purposely dragged out) or by hitting F12 (or the Dashboard key on newer Macs).

Read more about Dashboard at [Apple's page on the topic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2492).

Comment: A feature which users of other desktop environments (Gnome, ChromeOS, Windows, ...) expect to be standard and yet again here come the Mac with esoteric informational garbage (stocks) that looks nice, but isn't useful at all and you have to install 3rd party software to cover basic needs. Well Apple doesn't make much money out of MacOS, so it is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is natively but you can try [MagiCal](http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/magical) which adds an icon/calendar next to the time. Hasn't been updated in a while though, there's probably a lot of free apps out there that do the same thing.

Comment: iStat Menus does this--it used to be free, but sadly, no longer.

Comment: Personally I use [MenuCalendarClock iCal](http://www.objectpark.net/mcc.html) to just that (replace the clock and allow clicking to show a calendar with your events from iCal).

Comment: Seriously? I'm going to have to pay to get that functionality out of OS X? Bummer.

Comment: @JAG2007: If you don't use any of the advanced features of MenuCalendarClock iCal it's just nagware.

Comment: I've used iStat Menus and the old free version of iStat Menus, and they're both great if you don't mind using older software or paid software. :\ Maybe you could find an older version of iStat Menus that is free.

Comment: The last released free version of iStat Menus nags you every day about upgrading, so you'd have to get a prior revision.